Zustand: How to work with deeply nested state w/ Immer & TypeScript
I am using Zustand with Immer to create store in project I am working On. It has a deeply nested state of the following type Series:
      {
        id: 0,
        metaData: {},
        multipleGroupsRequireApproval: false,
        approvalStatus: ApprovalStatus.NO_APPROVAL,
        variants: Variant[] | null,
        items: Item[] | null,
      }[],

Upon the first render of Component I get data from backend in the same format and set it to the state. That's why there are bunch of nulls in the interface.
I have a method to approved state of a series:
setApprovalForCurrentSeries(seriesIndex, variantIndex) {
        set(
          produce((state: SeriesStore) => {
            const series = state.seriesArray[seriesIndex]
            if (series?.variants) {
              series.approvalStatus = ApprovalStatus.HAS_APPROVAL

              const variant = series.variants[variantIndex]

              if (variant) {
                variant.isApproved = true
              }
            }

            const items = series?.items|| []
            items.forEach((item) => {
              const itemVariants = item.variants || []
              const itemVariant = itemVariants[variantIndex]
              if (itemVariant) {
                itemVariant.isApproved = true
              }
            })
          }),
        )
      },

There will be several more methods and all of them change variants or items. Is there a way to pull out part where I do those if-statements to check whether an object exists? So that I could access desired objects directly.

It took me several days to figure it out. In fact, the answer is quite simple. My main problem was that I was trying to create a method using Zustand api with get() and sure enough it yelled at me, when I tried to mutate immutable entities.
So, I simply made a function that took in state as an argument and returned an object with all necessary data. Like so:
interface Result {
  series: Series | undefined
  seriesVariants: SeriesVariant[] | undefined
  selectedSeriesVariant: SeriesVariant | undefined
  items: Item[] | undefined
  selectedItemSeries: Item | undefined
}

And the method itself:
const safeUnwrap = (
  state: SeriesStore,
  seriesIndex: number,
  variantIndex: number | null,
  itemIndex: number | null,
): Result => {
  const result: Result = {
    series: undefined,
    seriesVariants: undefined,
    selectedSeriesVariant: undefined,
    items: undefined,
    selectedItemInSeries: undefined,
  }
  const series = state.seriesArray[seriesIndex]
  if (series) {
    result.series = series

    const variants = series?.variants
    const items = series.items
    if (variants) {
      result.seriesVariants = variants
      const variant = variantIndex && variants[variantIndex]

      if (variant) {
        result.selectedSeriesVariant = variant
      }
    }
    if (items) {
      result.items = items

      const item = itemIndex && items[itemIndex]
      if (item) {
        result.selectedItemInSeries = item
      }
    }
  }
  return result
}

This is far from being a pretty solution. But I can use this method to get only necessary values like:
const {variants} = safeUnwrapState(state, seriesIndex, null, null)

